# Add freemarker macro in jar library

Tags: java, freemarker

How can I add some freemarker macro (<#macro myMacro>...) in java jar library and after than use it (<@macro myMacro/>) in my  other web projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: embed a template file in your JAR library with a macro, e.g. a file `foo.ftl` with a macro `bar`.

Step 2: configure FreeMarker so that it can load templates from that JAR library. One way to do this is registering a `ClassTemplateLoader`, either by calling `Configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading` or by directly registering a `ClassTemplateLoader` (see [FreeMarker documentation about template loading](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#autoid_40)). Alternatively you can try to use a `URLTemplateLoader` or call `Configuration.setServletContextForTemplateLoading`, depending on your use case.

You maybe even have to combine such a `ClassTemplateLoader`/`URLTemplateLoader` with your currently used template loader in order to load templates from more than one location (see [MultiTemplateLoader](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#autoid_41)).

Step 3: import the macro template file into a namesapce from your main template via the [import directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_import.html), e.g.

```
<#import "foo.ftl" as foo>
```

Step 4: call the macro via its namespace, e.g.

```
<@foo.bar />
```

Done!